# Coin spin effect animation on grouped shapes

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs

I have been asked, using Konvajs, to work out an animation that will rotate a circle as if spinning on its central x-axis. So imagine a coin spinning on a table. The intention is to reveal some text on the circle. At the start the circle is fully visible as if from behind so no text visible, then it flips to reveal the text.

I have this code that does a rotation like a spinning wheel.

Can anyone give me a tween / animation approach that would achieve the spinning coin effect?

```
// the tween has to be created after the node has been added to the layer
var tween = new Konva.Tween({
    node: group,
    duration: 4,
    rotation: 360,
    easing: Konva.Easings.BackEaseOut
   }
}); 
tween.play();
```

After some research it looks like a 3D spin requires heavier lifting which may not be available or work well on mobile.

A good second-best appears to be using scaleX and animating from 0 > 1.

```
group.scaleX(0);
var tween = new Konva.Tween({
    node: group,
    duration: .25,
    scaleX: 1,
    easing: Konva.Easings.EaseOut
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the second-best version using scaleX() effect. Because of the need to calculate scaleX() and control visibility of the text so as to make it appear that the disc is solid, I moved away from a tween and over to an animation().

```js
// Set up the canvas / stage
var s1 = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 300, height: 200});

// Add a layer for line
var layer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
s1.add(layer);

// just a plain JS object to keep common variables in hand.
var cfg = { w: 300, h: 200, r: 80, txtSize: 520};

var group = new Konva.Group();
var circle = new Konva.Circle({x: cfg.w/2, y: cfg.h/2, radius: cfg.r, fill: 'DodgerBlue', stroke: 'DeepPink', strokeWidth: 5})
group.add(circle)


 var textValue = new Konva.Text({
  id: "t1",
  x: cfg.w/2,
  y: cfg.h/2,
  text: '',
  fill: 'DeepPink ',
  fontSize: cfg.txtSize
  });
group.add(textValue);
textValue.offset({x: textValue.getWidth()/2, y: textValue.getHeight()/2});

layer.add(group)

 // to spin a group about a point, set the offset to that point, then set the x & y to that point to !
 var pos = group.getClientRect();
 RotatePoint(group, {x: pos.x + pos.width/2, y: pos.y + pos.height/2});

// Everything is ready so draw the canvas objects set up so far.
s1.draw()


$('#st').on('click', function(){
  group.scaleX(1);
  var txt = $('#theText').val();
  setValue(txt);
})



// set the offset for rotation to the given location and re-position the shape
function RotatePoint(shape, pos){  // where pos = {x: xpos, y: yPos}
var initialPos = shape.getAbsolutePosition();
var moveBy = {x: pos.x - initialPos.x, y: pos.y - initialPos.y};

// offset is relative to initial x,y of shape, so deduct x,y.
shape.offsetX(moveBy.x);
shape.offsetY(moveBy.y);

shape.x(initialPos.x + moveBy.x);
shape.y(initialPos.y + moveBy.y);
}
 

var setValue = function(newText){

  // work out scaling to make text fit into the circle

  var txt = this.layer.find('#t1')[0];
  txt.text(newText).scale({x:1, y: 1})
  var txtSize = txt.getClientRect();

    var maxW = (cfg.r); // max allowed width of text
  var txtScaleW = (txtSize.width > maxW ? ( maxW / txtSize.width) : 1);

  var maxH = cfg.r; // max allowed height of text
  var txtScaleH = (txtSize.height > maxH ? ( maxH / txtSize.height) : 1);

  // finally decide which is the worst case and use that scaling
  var txtScale = ( txtScaleW > txtScaleH ? txtScaleH : txtScaleW);

    txt.scale({x: txtScale, y: txtScale});

    txt.offset({x: txt.getWidth()/2, y: txt.getHeight()/2});
  layer.draw()
 }
  
  // set initial text & spin !
  setValue('BBB');
  
  var anim, pos = 0, frameCnt = 0

  if (anim) {anim.stop(); }
  anim = new Konva.Animation(function(frame) {
    frameCnt = frameCnt + 1;
    
    if (frameCnt % 2 === 0){
      pos = pos + .2
      var scaleX = Math.sin(pos)
      textValue.visible(scaleX < 0 ? false : true);
      group.scaleX(scaleX);

      if (pos % 360 === 0){ console.log('spin') }
    }
    
    
  }, layer);
  

 anim.start();
```

```css
div
{
float: left;
margin: 0 5px;
}
p
{
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.min.js"></script>

<div  id='container1' style="width: 300px, height: 200px;"></div>
<div>
<p> <input type='text' id='theText' value='BBB' /> <button id='st'>Change text</button> </p> 
</div>
```