# Konva.js - draw on stage in time interval loop

Tags: konvajs

I am trying to draw multiple rectangles in time loop every 250ms using Konva.js, but the canvas updates only after loop is finish. What am I doing wrong?

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
        currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}


var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height,
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

for (let i=0; i < 10; i++){
    var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: i*25,
        y: 20,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        fill: 'red'
    });
    layer.add(rect1);
    layer.draw();
    sleep(250);
}
```

Comment: This is not the best way to handle animation delays. You should consider using a Konva.Animation which provides counters and time diffs that can be used without such a clunky delay mechanis,. The animation frame handles all the timing and gives you the best chance of coding realistic movement. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277899/coin-spin-effect-animation-on-grouped-shapes

Answer (score 0):

Your `sleep` method blocks main JS thread. You need to use async methods to wait. There are many ways to do that. With modern js you can do this:

```js
// noprotect
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);


const delay = (time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

async function startAddingShapes() {
  for (let i=0; i < 10; i++){
    const rect = new Konva.Rect({
      x: i*25,
      y: 20,
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      fill: 'red'
    });
    layer.add(rect);
    await delay(250);
 } 
}


startAddingShapes();
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/sahamulako/1/edit?html,js,output